# What are these double lines in Altium designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

[image: Image from Altium Designer]

I have a problem with Altium: I want to know what these lines are. They look like a net with 2 perpendicular lines, but I don't know what it is! It's very boring to design my circuit.

How do I disable it?

Comment: Have you got a bunch of components on the flip side of the circuit board that are hidden i.e. you've hidden the bottom layer but the nets still show up? This happens in PADs. Not quite the same but it looks similar.

Comment: Yes I have... but it's just 2 battery header (Keystone1048) so I only have 8 PADs at bottom... If I show the bottom, I alerady have the problem...

Comment: If I reduce the ZOOM, it disappears... but i need to ZOOM for drawing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are error markers (they indicate that your nets are not connected). Go to the Menu, select "Reset Error Markers", I think it's under design or Tools.